# R - have trouble reading CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I need to analyze data in .csv files but those files have a problem that the second row is always dashes. Please see example below:

```
participant_id  participant_name    N371    N2062

--------------  ----------------    ----    -----

229182         John Kim  0   0
```

`read.csv` or `fread` is not able to read this file correctly until I open these files and manually delete the second row. However, it is a pain and those files will be updated weekly. I am wondering if there is a way that I can read these files correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a different problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007684/unable-to-get-column-names-when-using-skip-along-with-read-csv but the same solution should works. HTH

Comment: @PereG I tried to get the header first but got this error. > all.ba = fread("C:/Users/sample.csv", nrows = 1)
Error in fread("C:/Users/sample.csv",  : 
  embedded nul in string: 'ÿþp\0r\0o\0j\0e\0c\0t\0_\0n\0a\0m\0e\0'

Comment: trying adding `skip=1` in your `read.csv()` function. Something like this might work: `data = read.csv("C:/Users/sample.csv",header = T, skip=1)`

Comment: You could also specify the column types in `colclasses` and simply drop the first row afterwards. This will make sure your columns are read in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. But still not working: > all.ba = read.csv("C:/Users/sample.csv", header = T, skip = 1,
+                   colClasses=c("character",rep("integer",3),"character",rep("integer",350)))
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  empty beginning of file
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, skip) : line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case you can use the `comment.char` argument:

```
text <- "participant_id participant_name N371 N2062
-------------- ---------------- --- ----
  229182 'John Kim' 0 0" 

df <- read.table(text = text, header=T, comment.char = "-")

> df
  participant_id participant_name N371 N2062
1         229182         John Kim    0     0
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But still got error: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
...